# Apache virtual host issue with modrewrite and css files

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have an Apache virtual host for a project I have done using Silex which is based on Symfony2 however the routing works fine with the modrewrite rules but all calls to javascript or css seem to turn into routes to a controller. Could you help me with the virtual host please.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site/www
```

Comment: Where's this configuration?

Comment: in the httpd.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is relative the the DocumentRoot. The above works within a `<Directory...>` block (or .htaccess file). Try changing it to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```